# Foreign Key on unique index doesn't work with NULL column

Tags: sql-server, database

I am struggling with a foreign key on a unique index in SQL Server, which isn't quite working as expected.

My table structure is like this:

- Table mm1 has a nonclustered PK-Index on a surrogate key column id

  - Additionally mm1 has a clustered unique index on three columns (one of them is nullable)
  - Table mm2 links on those three columns via a foreign key

The creation of these objects doesn't throw any errors. However, the foreign key is not evaluted properly and allows for non-existing values in mm1 to be inserted in mm2. This seems to be related on the nullable column c....if I set the foreign key on just columns a and b it works as expected.

Can you explain this behaviour? Why allowing to define a unique index including null in the first place but not supporting it properly in foreign key constraints? Is there a way to achieve correct results without changing contents of table mm2?

Here's a little repro script:

```
CREATE table mm1 (
    id int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    a varchar(50) not null,     
    b int not null, 
    c int null, 
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED(id))

CREATE table mm2 (
    id int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    a varchar(50) not null,
    b int not null,
    c int null,
    d varchar(10),
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED(id))

CREATE  UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX  idx_mm1_mm_fkTest1 ON mm1(a,b,c)

ALTER TABLE mm2
ADD CONSTRAINT  fk_mm2_mm_fkTest1 
FOREIGN KEY (a,b, c)  REFERENCES mm1(a,b,c)

ALTER TABLE mm2 CHECK CONSTRAINT fk_mm2_mm_fkTest1;

INSERT INTO mm1 VALUES ('abc', 1, 2);

INSERT INTO mm2 
(a,b,d) VALUES('sa',1,'sad')

SELECT * FROM mm2;
```

Comment: NULL isn't a value. It means nothing at all. It can't be compared for equality. SQL has some strange rules about NULLs, but the most important thing is that you *can't* treat them as values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not at all sure what I would expect this to do.   The more I think about it, the less sense it makes.

NULL is evaluated in these contexts to mean UNKNOWN.  With an unknown in a foreign key you can never be sure which row it refers to in the first place.  In other words, this constraint makes no semantic sense.

Use a default value and have your foreign key hit non-null values only.  If you allow NULLs in foreign keys they will be dangling anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and the fresh up on the meaning of null. Well I'm trying to avoid to migrate data from a lot of tables where this value can be null (and null has the meaning of "not present" in this context). I now chose to use a persisted computed column which converts the NULL-value to a real value and put the foreign key on that. Not exactly elegant and nothing I am proud of but still saves my day of getting consistency alongside of not rewriting core parts of the app.

Comment: Therefore the computed column gets my default value...using a default value on the original columns will break things as a lot of code is filtering on that column being null.

Comment: Yes, that is totally a reasonable approach.

Comment: How does it not make sense? unique index on definitionId, variantId: (1, null) and (1, 1) are both valid, but (1, null) and (1, null) are not valid