# MYSQL - Unable to create foreign index with onDelete set null on existing table

Tags: mysql

I have two table with data.

```
users
id | name | email

articles
id | user_id (nullable) | title
```

Right now in articles user_id doesn't have any index or foreign index, and sometimes user_id is null.

Now I try to create foreign index to table users with condition 'user_id' set null on delete.

```
alter table articles
    add constraint articles_users_id_fk
        foreign key (user_id) references users (id)
            on delete set null;
```

But I have following error.

> [23000][1452] Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
> constraint fails (`test-db`.`#sql-1_15`, CONSTRAINT
> `articles_users_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`
> (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL)

How to create index if in table I have already some null values.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425411/foreign-key-on-unique-index-doesnt-work-with-null-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that there are existing rows in the `articles` table with `user_id` values that don't have corresponding matching values in the `users` table.

When you try to create a foreign key constraint with the `ON DELETE SET NULL` option, MySQL ensures that the referenced values exist in the parent table (`users` in this case) before allowing you to set the child value (`user_id` in `articles`) to `NULL`. This is why you're getting the foreign key constraint error.

Make sure all existing `user_id` values in `articles` are valid or NULL. For example, if a `user_id` doesn't exist in `users`, you can set it to `NULL` or update it to a valid user ID.

Now create indexes on `users` and `articles` tables.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX idx_users_id (id);
ALTER TABLE articles ADD INDEX idx_articles_user_id (user_id);
```

Now add the foreign key constraint

```
ALTER TABLE articles
ADD CONSTRAINT articles_users_id_fk
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
ON DELETE SET NULL;
```